# slf4j - logging to few implementations at the same time

Tags: logging, slf4j, appender

1. How to make slf4j use few implementations `(appenders)` if a want to log to console AND file both? (something similar to configuring log4j using loj4.properties file)
2. How to do my own slf4j impl? Just implement interface and it will be found on the classpath automatically?

Answer (score 1):

SLF4J just a simple facade: *"The Simple Logging Facade for Java or (SLF4J) serves as a simple facade or abstraction for various logging frameworks, e.g. java.util.logging, log4j and logback, allowing the end user to plug in the desired logging framework at deployment time. "* (From http://www.slf4j.org/)

So you need an implementation too which could print or save your log messages. There are some options: http://www.slf4j.org/manual.html#swapping I'd choose [Logback](http://logback.qos.ch/). Check the [logback manual, Chapter 4: Appenders](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html) also.

Comment: thank you.as far as i understand, it searches impementations in runtime (classpath) and use found impl. is there an opportunity to use all found implementations, not the first found one? i think that relates to slf4j, not implementations. even if i develop my own wrapper impl that passes invokation to all found impls, there is no guarantee that my wrapper will be used instead of other available impls on the classpath

Answer (score 0):

1. You confuse here implementations with appenders. An **appender** is a physical logging target (a file, console, etc.) and it's a term from log4j or logback, which are slf4j **implementations**. SLF4J does not know about appenders.
2. SLF4J is designed to work with one implementation at a time. If you need to use many, you'd have to implement `org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder` yourself, and put it in the classpath as the only class with this name, and route your logging inside this class. I'm still not sure, though, if this is what you want.

Comment: Thanks. I understand that slf4j usage itself it almost useless for me (i did not use different implementations or switch between them).

Comment: @user781137 No, I think it's worth it anyway. It costs nothing and you can switch implementation any time, should there problems occur. If it's a standalone application, you're probably fine, in advanced exec. environments this may come handy.